# SQL statement in Java DAO method is not checking if user exists properly

Tags: java, sql, return, dao, executequery

I have DAO method in Java which looks like this:

```java
private boolean validateUser(String email, String username) throws SQLException {
    return stmt.execute(
        "SELECT NOT EXISTS" +
        "(SELECT id from Math_Hub.Users_Information " +
        "WHERE username = '" + username + "' OR email = '" + email + "')");
}
```

The method returns true even if username already exists in database. Why is that?

I tried to test it by hand and the following SQL statement

```sql
SELECT NOT EXISTS
(SELECT id from Math_Hub.Users_Information
WHERE username = 'Eren' OR email = 'erenyeager@gmail.com')
```

This worked perfectly.

Comment: Please use [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). As is, your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS always return 1 if no row matches in the where clauses. Either use EXISTS or you can go with select query and later check if anything is received in the resultset( select * or select count(*)).